# Passing variable to class c#

Tags: c#, class

I have a class with a printing form made with ItextSharp. I use same form of IthextSharp in few places, so I thought class will be a good thing to do. Works great, but what if I want to pass some data to that class like price or just the patch and name of file to create?

So there I have two string path and FileName that are set in class, but how can I pass them from my form with button click event that starts the class?

Beginning of class code:

```cs
public static bool PDFGenerateOffer 
{
    get
    {
        string path = @"C:\Offers\";
        string FileName = "PC2";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
                    
        Document pdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 20f, 20f);
        PdfWriter pWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdoc, new FileStream(path + FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
        pdoc.Open();
```

And simple code made for button click event just to start class:

```cs
private void btnSaveOffer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ClassPDFOfferPC.PDFGenerateOffer == true)
    {
        AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"C:\\Ooffers\\" + "PC.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never heard the expression "start a class". What do you mean by that?

Comment: That's not what properties are for. There shouldn't be all sorts of weird side effects when getting the value of a property.

Comment: And by the way: @"\\" is two backslashes. You would want to either loose one, or loose the @.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use it like a method.

```cs
public static bool PDFGenerateOffer(string filePath)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
    }
        
    Document pdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 20f, 20f);
    PdfWriter pWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdoc, new FileStream(filePath + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    pdoc.Open();
}
```

**usage**

```cs
if (ClassPDFOfferPC.PDFGenerateOffer(@"C:\\Ooffers\\" + "PC") == true)
{
    AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"C:\\Ooffers\\" + "PC.pdf");
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to access this itextsharp in like 50 places in my program? That is why I was thinkign about the class...

Comment: im not able to understand what you mean  by `itextsharp`. then you have call 50 time that's why you have  methods. and  `get` will internally create a method as well. if you worried about passing it all the time create a static variable and assign the file path pass it around your application.

Comment: Actually iTextSharp is a using for pdf creating, doesn't mutter, sense is same. So just create form, not class, and acces it frmOffer.PDFGenerateOffer (string filepath, string filename) ?

Comment: I don't see any problem in creating in class. can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do in question(you can edit it ). i will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As always: It depends. There are many ways.

- You can use the solution of Avinash Reddy
- You can pass parameters to the constructor of your class
- You can inherit and create PdfClassWithSpecialParameters
- ...

Comment: Please show us how these options work..